# How to fix such RegExp bug in jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery-tokeninput

I am using [jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) autocomplete plugin for the list of programming languages and I have found out, that it does not handle a "+" character in "C++": it returns a JavaScript error and nothing appears on autocomplete list.

When I enter "C" ir returns the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
>   /(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(C++)(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)/: Nothing to repeat

The problem seems to be in [a small method with RegExp statement](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/blob/master/src/jquery.tokeninput.js#L702):

```
function find_value_and_highlight_term(template, value, term) {
    return template.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + value + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "g"), highlight_term(value, term));
}
```

Variables:

```
template = "<li>C++</li>";
value = "C++";
term = "C";
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is a special modifier in regexes which means "match one or more of the previous thing". To match against a literal `'+'` character, escape it with a `\`

```
/(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>])(C\+\+)(?![^<>]>)(?![^&;]+;)/
```

To escape all special characters:

```
function escapeRegex(str) {
  return str.replace(/[-\/\\$\^*+?.()|\[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

var re = new RegExp(escapeRegex('[.*?]'));
```

Comment: Is there any method, that would make any string regexp-safe? For example: (" + regexp_safe(value) + ")

Comment: Found it: http://simonwillison.net/2006/Jan/20/escape/#p-6 - it is working fine now. Thank you.

Comment: @Apolo I added a function which does that

Answer (score 0):

Just replace that regexp function with splice and strpos version of that function.
It work better and faster, it will not have any problems with any special characters.

here is the function:

```js
function find_value_and_highlight_term(template, value, term) {
  var templateLc = template.toLowerCase();
  var strpos = templateLc.indexOf(term);
  if(strpos) {
    var strlen = term.length;
    var templateStart = template.slice(0,strpos);
    var templateEnd = template.slice(strpos+strlen);
    return templateStart+"<b>"+term+"</b>"+templateEnd;
  } else {
    return template;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats not really what the OP wanted.

Comment: i really can t understand why my answer is not valid...the OP want to fix the problem...related to that specific plugin...The first and most voted answer does not work properly! The plugin stop to highlight the searched text...so my solution is better....I really don't understand why being so finicky with not a good reason....what is the question?? Is it how to fix this plugin? Or it's about regexp philosophy??? please anwer i will avoid to waste any other minute trying to help if you still think my answer is not valid..........!

Answer (score 0):

```
Here I have found solution of "c++" string during searching in tokeninput js.
you just search code in jquery.tokeninput.js and replace with code below.

here are the function:

 function regexSanitize( str ) {
   return str.replace(/([.+*?:\[\](){}|\\])/g, "\\$1");
  }

  function highlight_term(value, term) {
    return value.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + regexSanitize(value) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<b>$1</b>");
    }



 function find_value_and_highlight_term(template, value, term) {
       return template.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + regexSanitize(value) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "g"), highlight_term(value, term)
);
```

}